# Just want someone to explain to me what they exactly mean. Its a Codecademy Question

Tags: python, string, substring

Was doing a question from the Python section of codecademy. Came across this question. I did solve it but I checked their hint afterwards to know and understand their way of doing things. Didn't really get it. Could someone please explain it to me?

This is the question:

"Write a function named substring_between_letters that takes a string named word, a single character named start, and another character named end. This function should return the substring between the first occurrence of start and end in word. If start or end are not in word, the function should return word."

For example, substring_between_letters("apple", "p", "e") should return "pl"

This was the hint they gave that I didn't understand and need explaining:

"Begin by finding the indices of the start and end characters by using word.find(start) and word.find(end).

If either of those indices are -1, then the original string didn’t contain one of those characters, and you should return word.

If neither are -1, then slice word using those indices. Remember, slicing is [inclusive:exclusive]!"

Just didn't get the part about the negative indices. I know what negative indices are but how does it matter in this context?

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) is your friend. If you neglect to consult the Python documentation while you are trying to learn, the process will be harder.

Answer (score 0):

`str. find` returns -1 if the character is not found. They're saying you should check for that case first before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code will make it clearer -

```
def substring_between_letters(word, s, e):
    i = word.find(s), word.find(e)
    
    if -1 in i:
        return word
    else:
        return word[i[0]+1:i[1]]
    
print(substring_between_letters('apple', 'p','e'))
#OUTPUT - 'pl'

print(substring_between_letters('hello', 'p','e'))
#OUTPUT - 'hello'
```

What you need to do is to get the substring between the start index and the end index, which you can find by doing `word.find()`. But since the first index will be inclusive and the second one is exclusive, you have to start from start_index +1 to end_index to get the string in between after exluding the starting and ending character. If any of the characters is not present, then `word.find` returns a -1. In that case, you can simply return the whole word.